# How can I simplify a chained set of LOOKUP in Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Currently, I have a sheet where each row has ~20 cells that I evaluate using LOOKUP. If the row isn't empty, I grab a value from reference row. If it is empty, I assign 0 as its value, to avoid getting #N/A returned.

Once I evaluate each of the 20 rows, I want to then SUM all of the rows. While I have a formula that works, it's hideous:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",H2,H91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",I2,I91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",J2,J91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",K2,K91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",L2,L91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",M2,M91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",N2,N91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",O2,O91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",P2,P91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",Q2,Q91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",R2,R91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",S2,S91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",T2,T91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",U2,U91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",V2,V91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",W2,W91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",X2,X91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",Y2,Y91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",Z2,Z91),0) + IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",AA2,AA91),0)
+ IFERROR(LOOKUP("X",AB2,AB91),0))
```

The full example is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xf92nnYVoxtXVcD2EY5qwvbyc4QPnebt5repBNNiA1Y/edit#gid=846310386):

See cells Y2 thru Y87 for the the formula.

I know there must be a more elegant way to do this, but alas, my Google Sheet skills are novice at best.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:W2="X")*1,$C$91:$W$91)
```

Or more to the point a simple SUMIF()

```
=SUMIF(C2:W2,"X",$C$91:$W$91)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, Scott!

Comment: @J.Simpson I am glad to have helped.